# Unable to close the dialog

Tags: eclipse, swt, jface, e4

I am trying to open a dialog in swt where I Override the createDialogArea method for customise my dialog. In this method I am trying to openQuestion MessageDialog. Open that dialog If openQuestion message return yes otherwise close the dialog before open it. When I click on Cancel on OpenQuestion Dialog I got an exception.

```java
@Override
protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
    private boolean m_firstQuery = true;
    getShell().setText("Test");

    Composite composite = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
    composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));

    final Display display = Display.getCurrent();
    boolean moveOn = true;
    if (m_firstQuery) {
         moveOn = MessageDialog.openQuestion(display .getActiveShell(),
                "Do you want to open the dialog?", "Yes/No");
         if (!moveOn) {
             this.close();
         }

        m_firstQuery = false;
    }

    return composite;
}
```

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument not valid
 at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4533)
 at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4467)
 at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4438)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:448)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkParent(Widget.java:285)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.<init>(Widget.java:151)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.<init>(Control.java:110)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.<init>(Scrollable.java:82)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.<init>(Composite.java:96)
 at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.createButtonBar(Dialog.java:648)
 at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.createContents(Dialog.java:769)
 at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:426)
 at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1096)
 at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:783)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `close` directly in `createDialogArea`, the JFace dialog code expects the dialog to remain valid all the way through creating the dialog.

You can use `Display.asyncExec` to delay the close until the dialog is open. Replace `this.close()` with:

```java
display.asyncExec(() -> close());
```

However it would be better to display the message box before you try to create the dialog in the first place.